# Solving a system of two trigonometric equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

I have to solve the following system made of two equations.

- The variables are $x_i$ for $i=1,...,n$.
- For the parameters, we have $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ and $B\geq0$.

The two equations are:
$$\sum_{i=1}^na_i\cos(x_i)=B,$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^na_i\sin(x_i)=0.$$

I see a condition of existence: we must have $B\leq \sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|$.

But are there any other conditions?
And my main question is: how could I find a solution to such equations?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: What are the unknowns ? With just $2$ equations, you can solve for $2$ unknowns at most.

Comment: @YvesDaoust He probably meant what is the solution space.

Comment: If all $a_i = 0$, then the solution space is any $n$-tuple of $x$, if $B = 0$, or empty otherwise. And if say $a_n \ne 0$, then you probably should break the symmetry for this component. And it probably will be easier to solve if reformulate it with the complex exponential.

Comment: Geometrically speaking, it is a (not necessarily convex) polygon on the complex plane, with $n$ edges of lengths $a$, where the first vertex is at the origin and the last one is at the point $(B, 0)$; here $x$ are the slopes of the edges relative to the real line. So what you're asking is basically what is the space of all such $n$-gons, and how to parametrize this space.

Comment: Also the problem may be restricted to the case of $a_i$ and $B$ being positive: by addition of half a circle ($pi$) to the $x_i$, and exclusion of zero coefficients.

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky: solution space for what unknowns ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The angles $x_i$, or the directions $s_i$, or slopes of edges? (see my "answer" BTW)

Comment: @AndrewMiloradovsky: your saying. I am waiting for the OP's comment.

Answer (score 1):

This describes an articulated arm with section lengths $a_i$.

With a single section, you reach the circle of radius $a_0$.

With two sections, you can sweep the above circle by moving its center on the circle of radius $a_1$. Then you can reach any point in the ring of radii $r_1=|a_0-a_1|$ and $R_1=a_0+a_1$. For such a point, there are two solutions.

With a third section and more, you can sweep the above ring and reach the points between the radii $r_k=r_{k-1}-a_k$ and $R_k=R_{k-1}+a_k$. For the inner radius, if some permutation of the sections leads to a negative value, the whole disk can be reached. For these points, there is a multiple infinity ($k-2$) of solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can reformulate the problem using complex exponentiation

$$B - \sum_{i=1}^n a_i s_i = 0$$

$$s_k = \exp(i x_k)$$

And interpret it as a polygon space of varied angles in vertices.
It doesn't look like a simple problem. This may be of use:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.237.2549

(You might also want to ask it on MathOverflow.)